# Filegroup per Table partition - remove filegroup and re-add filegroup

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, partitioning, filegroups

I've seaching all over the web for a solution, if it is even possible... I'm not a savvy in Partitioned tables in different filegroups...

Our software is supported by SQL 2008 R2 SP2 to SQL 2017 for Express to enterprise editions (99% are setup with Simple recovery model).  I have a big table that I want to Partition into different filegroups by month (each file group will have only one partition).  I've read about the Switch, Merge and Split functionalities and the filegroup functionalities of adding and removing... but I haven't found an article that uses this to backup a filegroup.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to somehow remove the oldest file group once a month, but without deleting the content... I woud then keep these monthly files  somewhere as a backup.  If ever I need to query data from one of the old file groups, I would re-add the filegroup and re-add it to the partition...

Our software is distributed to thousands of customers.
Due to the fact that there is a 10GB limitation of SQL Server express, I want to keep the database at a decent size and keep older months accessible by creating a procedure that would "re-attach" that data to the table for querying purposes.

Is it even possible?